# file src versioning in gulp generated file

Tags: caching, gulp

We use  gulp plugins https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iconfont and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iconfont-css to generate icon-font and css respectively. The fonts are cached in Chrome so I want to add version number at the end of the font source string in styles.css.

Here is a part of the  generated css I want to  transform

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: "some-icons";
    url('/assets/fonts/some-icons.woff2') format('woff2');
  }
```

The desired output is

```
  @font-face {
        font-family: "some-icons";
        url('/assets/fonts/some-icons.woff2?v=someVersion') format('woff2');
      }
```

where someVersion is a timestamp or some other random string that will distinguish the file from its previous version.

I'm looking for a gulp plugin that will parse css and add "salt" at the end of the  src string.

Other solutions are welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution leveraging this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-modify-file. Here is the  basic gulp task: it looks for some-icons.woff2 in the  file content and  replaces it with some-icons.woff2?v=timestamp

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const modify = require('gulp-modify-file');

const timestamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);

gulp.task('modify', ()=> {
  return gulp.src('tmp/styles.css')
    .pipe(modify(
      (content, path, file)=> {
        content = content.replace('some-icons.woff2', 'some-icons.woff2?v=' + timestamp);

        return `${content}`
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Comment: @Napolux, enjoy)