# How to add version to file using gulp?

Tags: gulp

I need to add version to file. e.g font.otf?v=452155

I tried gulp-rename but it doesn't help.
I need to add version after extension.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
gulp.task('addTimestampToFont', function(callback) {
gulp.src('../../fonts/icons/Icons.*')
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: '?v=' + timestamp
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../fonts/'));
callback();
});
```

Comment: I found solution here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222788/file-src-versioning-in-gulp-generated-file
I added version on a few files. But I think it's not 
convenient if you need to add version to lots of files.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [gulp-version-number](http://npmjs.com/package/gulp-version-number) :

```
const addVersionString = require("gulp-version-number");


const versionConfig = {
  "value": "%DT%",
  "append": {
    "key": "v",
    "to": ["css", "js"],
  },
}

function processHTML() {
  return gulp.src(paths.html.src)
    .pipe(print())

    // modifyHTMLlinks: remove browserSync script link
    // update css/js links to .min.css or .min.js
    .pipe(modifyHTMLlinks())

    .pipe(stripComments.html(stripOptions))

    // add ?v=dateTime stamp to css and js links
    .pipe(addVersionString(versionConfig))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.deploy));
}
```